# JPA+ Hibernate+ Maven + NetBeans = HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, netbeans

I have been trying to figure it out for a few days but today I gave up. I got the HTTP Status Error when I try to create Entity Manager Factory.

Full Stack Trace:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Error processing webservice request

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error processing webservice request
    org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:98)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

<openjpa-3.0.0-r422266:1833209 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The persistence provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties are available in the configuration: "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@393fa2d". 
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:71)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:850)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:603)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1520)
    org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:533)
    org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:458)
    org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:122)
    org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
    org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
    org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:1035)
    org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:1026)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:643)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:154)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:246)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:162)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:152)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:58)
    dao.Dao.getUser(Dao.java:15)
    tk.spartan.controller.GetUser.list(GetUser.java:35)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
    org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:68)
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:253)
    org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

So it's a little weird that I get openjpa error when in persistance.xml I've got :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="baza" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>beans.User</class>


        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="bd2a4c789dfa24" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                                  value="jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-02.cleardb.net/heroku_48a75ca44077046?reconnect=true" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>  -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>

            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>

            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="true"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

and my Entity class looks like:

```
package beans;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")

public class User {

    @Column(name = "iduser")
    @Id
    private Integer iduser;

    @Column(name = "user")
    private String user;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int iduser, String user, String pass, String role) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User(Integer iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }

    public Integer getIduser() {
        return iduser;
    }

    public void setIduser(Integer iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

So I'm a little bit confused right now. I've been searching for that kind of error but i didn't find a solution for that.

What it could be?

Added:

```
@Path("user")
public class GetUser 
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)


    public List<User> list ()
            {

    Dao dao = new Dao();
    User user = new User();


    List<User> userListed = dao.getUser(user);


    return userListed;
            }
```

[and structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsiQr.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237314/a-jdbc-driver-or-datasource-class-name-must-be-specified-in-the-connectiondriver might help you.

Comment: You post a persistence unit for Hibernate yet you are using OpenJPA (in the exception), so perhaps you are actually pointing to the wrong persistence unit (define HOW you are invoking the persistence unit, where the `persistence.xml` is stored, etc ... start from `tk.spartan.controller.GetUser.list(GetUser.java:35)`). Kindly post consistent information.

Comment: I've added class GetUser and project's structure

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include mysql driver to your jar dependency(pom.xml).
The error message said: The driver is unknown.